# UWP CustomControl Styles don't inherit from default styles

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm creating a custom control (not UserControl) and I put my default style in `generic.xaml`.  Since I'm basing my control on CheckBox, and I'm not really doing anything interesting other than adding some extra logic on the backend and maybe overriding a single property I would like to base my styles on the default styles.

Previously, I would be able to do something like

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCheckBox" BasedOn="CheckBox">
  <Setter Property="..." Value="..." />
</Style>
```

And this would use the default style and override my single property.  Is this possible in UWP apps or do I need to copy the entire built-in style and change my single property?

My class is defined like this:

```
public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public MyCheckBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCheckBox);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: You have to give style reference to BasedOn. refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.style.basedon

Comment: BasedOn what?  That's my actual question.  How do I refer to the builtin default styles?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCheckBox" BasedOn="CheckBox">
  <Setter Property="..." Value="..." />
</Style>
```

> And this would use the default style and override my single property. Is this possible in UWP apps or do I need to copy the entire built-in style and change my single property?

By my side, if I use `BasedOn="CheckBox"` and place a `MyCheckBox` in the MainPage, this error will occur:

> The name "MyCheckBox" does not exist in the namespace "xxxx".
>
> Invalid value for property 'BasedOn':...
>
> Cannot assign text value 'CheckBox' into property 'BasedOn' of type 'Style'.

If you want to use `BasedOn` style here, you can refer to [Use based-on styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/styling-controls#use-based-on-styles). According to this doc, you will need to use `StaticResource` here.

But I don't think here only using `BasedOn` style can solve the problem. Yes you are right, CustomControl style doesn't inherit from default styles, as you can see, the generic.xaml includes a default style, in this style there are only a `ControlTemplate` and a `Border`, it's empty.

> Since I'm basing my control on CheckBox, and I'm not really doing anything interesting other than adding some extra logic on the backend and maybe overriding a single property I would like to base my styles on the default styles.

If I understand your request correctly, since the customcontrol's template is fast empty, so you are also right, you will need to copy the entire built-in style. For example, you can modify the template the same as the `CheckBox`'s `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,5,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="local:MyCheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCheckBox">
                <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="Transparent" Height="20" Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20" />
                        <FontIcon x:Name="CheckGlyph" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE001;" Opacity="0" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But I think you can also modify the template of your customcontrol like this:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="local:MyCheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCheckBox">
                <CheckBox Content="222" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This will make your `CustomControl` getting the default style of `CheckBox`, so which single property do you want to change?

Comment: Unfortunately the shortened solution doesn't work.  I'm adding extra logic to the CheckBox control and with this design it's the inner checkbox that's going to have all of that logic.  As an example, if I set IsChecked on a `MyCheckBox` object, I would need to manually set the value of my inner checkbox in code.

Comment: @BenRandall, Yes, you are right. But I was suggesting to complete the style and logic code inside of the control and expose some needed properties like a usercontrol.